# No aparece el componente Timer en visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

estoy intentando hacer uso del componente del visual studio timer.
Pero este no me aparece para ser usado.
tengo instalado el visual studio 2017.

Comment: Hola, te doy la bienvenida a [es.so], te sugiero completar el [tour] para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Answer (score 0):

Binevenido!

En VS 2017, de manera predeterminada, el control del timer de Winforms está en la ventana de la caja de herramientas. Si no puede encontrar el control del timer, intenta usar los siguientes pasos para agregarlo:

En la Caja de herramientas, céntrese en la pestaña "Todos los formularios de Windows", haga clic con el botón derecho y luego haga clic en "Elegir elementos ..."

En el cuadro de diálogo "Elegir elementos de la caja de herramientas", escribe "Temporizador" o "Timer" en el cuadro de texto de Filtro, luego busque el timer para verificar en la pestaña "Componentes de .NET Framework"

Haga clic en el botón "OK"

Resultado: el control del timer se agregará en la pestaña "Todos los formularios de Windows" de la ventana de la caja de herramientas.

Puede consultar la siguiente captura de pantalla, por favor avíseme si tiene alguna pregunta al respecto.

[image: Añadir el timer en VS2007]

Suerte!